# Services module: What is 'Index' operation?

Tags: services, 8

[image]

D7 / Services 3.2

retrieve / create / update / delete are very straightforward, make senses to me that matching 'CRUD', I don't understand what 'index' here does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

'Index' in services module will list out an entity(node, users, taxonomy..)  in descending Order of its created time, vid, name etc based on the arguments that are passed. The common arguments for the Index are

1. `page`  - Page number of results to return (in pages of 20).
2. `fields` - The fields you want returned.
3. `parameters` - An array containing fields and values used to build a sql WHERE clause indicating items to retrieve. (array)
4. `pagesize` - number of items to be returned. (Integer)

   In case of retrieve, it returns the complete entity object of the passed 'entity_id'

**UPDATED:**

Sample URLS for Index is

- http://domain/endpoint/node?fields=nid,vid&parameters[nid]=7&parameters[uid]=1&page=2
- http://domain/endpoint/taxonomy_term?fields=tid,name&parameters[tid]=7&parameters[vid]=1
- http://domain/endpoint/user?fields=uid,name,mail&parameters[uid]=1
- http://domain/endpoint/node?pagesize=3

For documentation you can see [Services: An API for remote applications](https://www.drupal.org/node/109782).

Comment: How do I construct the 'index' argument in uri? e.g page argument. Is it something like:  http://<domain>/<endpoint>/<resource>/page/3 ? Is there any documentation on the web? (i am having hard time searching for docs)

Comment: @ gilzero I have updated the answer.

Comment: @DineshKumar Now if I want to create a pagination in js, I will need to know the total count of data. How can I find that?

Answer (score 0):

services module provides some endpoints with resources.
`index` will return all the nodes depends on the resource you selected.
in this case suppose `node` is a resource and URL looks like this - `http://domain/endpoint/node` with a `GET` Request will return all the nodes.